# How to manage prod vs dev environment secrets in Expo EAS builds?

Tags: expo

What is the best way to handle production vs. development environmental variables regarding the Secrets stored in expo.dev for Expo EAS builds?

Do you keep separate variables and then code in-app to choose?
in expo.dev Secrets...
`DEV_STORAGE_BUCKET`
`PROD_STORAGE_BUCKET`

then in-app...
`const storageBucket = __DEV__ ? DEV_STORAGE_BUCKET : PROD_STORAGE_BUCKET`

Is there a better approach?